# Filter just one html tag with php

Tags: php, html, string, strip-tags

I have a php variable (`$string`) that contains a block of text (with html tags). What I want to do is filter just one tag: the `<object></object>`.

Haven't found any solution so far ...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code, the input, and the desired output.

Comment: This is a good time to learn about [PHP RegEx Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php)

Comment: by filter do you mean that you want to allow only that tag, or remove only that tag?

Comment: @Jonathan I want to remove only that tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DOMDocument::loadhtml` to get the html from the `$string` you can use it like this :

```
<?php
    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    //Parsing the string into html  
    @$DOM->loadHTML($string);
    //Getting all the elements with the <object> tag
    $objects = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("object");
?>
```

read more about the `DOMDocument` Class in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).